# Function generating all primes?

Tags: prime-numbers

As far as I know, no one has been able to find an onto function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow P$ where $P$ is the set of all primes.
Does there exist an onto function $f: \mathbb{N}\times  \mathbb{N} \rightarrow P$ where $P$ is the set of all primes?
Finally, is there any general onto function $f:\mathbb{N}^k \rightarrow P$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$?
Of course what i want is a closed form that is, something like a formula. Not a function like f(n)= nth prime number.

Comment: Sure there is an onto function $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow P$. Take for instance $f(n) = p_n$, the $n$th prime. If you want a _formula_ instead, that's a different question.

Comment: @TonyK obviously I am talking about a function with a close form, something like a formula.

Comment: Yes, obviously. But if you are going to ask such questions, it's important that you get the terminology right.

Comment: @TonyK I apologize for my mistake, yeah I should have said closed form... Sorry.... Yes a open form is what i want..... :)

Comment: Any answers, please people!!              @tonyk i have edited the question.

Comment: Your question is too broad to admit a precise answer (are you only interested in polynomials, or some broader class of "formulas"?), but this might be a good place to do some background reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes